# Template Class Friend Function of Another Template Class

Tags: class, function, templates, private

I have a tree comprised of a pair of template classes, one of which needs access to private members of the other, preferably restricted to only those member functions which actually need access. This is a simplified illustration of my classes:

```
//  Forward declaration
template <typename K, typename V> class Tree;

template <typename K, typename V> class Node {
    public:
        typedef typename Node<K, V>* NodeP;

        // ...
    private:
        K key;
        V val;

        //  Child nodes
        NodeP left;
        NodeP right;
};

template <typename K, typename V> class Tree {
    public:
        typedef typename Node<K, V>::NodeP NodeP;

        // ...

        void clear() { del(root); }
    private:

        //  Root node
        NodeP root;

        void del(NodeP start)
        {
            if (start->left != NULL)
                del(start->left);
            if (start->right != NULL)
                del(start->right);
            delete start;
        }
};
```

What I can't figure out is how to declare `del()` (and other member functions of Tree) as a `friend` of the Node class. I've tried making the whole class a `friend`, with this line:

`template <typename K, typename V> friend class Tree;`

That compiles, but this:

`template <typename K, typename V> friend void Tree<K, V>::del(NodeP);`

... doesn't. I'm wondering if I'm making them too dependent on instances of each other? Is there a way to do what I want to do? Thanks.